# Deprecated: Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion [PHP, TCPDF, hexdec()]

Tags: php, tcpdf

I've incorporated tcpdf into a php file (I'm using this exact example: https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_006/) and in trying to generate the pdf I'm getting the following error:

```
Deprecated: Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored in C:\wamp64\www\projects\include\tcpdf_colors.php on line 388
```

Reference code snippet for error - tcpdf_colors.php (lines 370-390):

```
// HEXADECIMAL REPRESENTATION
switch (strlen($color_code)) {
    case 3: {
        // 3-digit RGB hexadecimal representation
        $r = substr($color_code, 0, 1);
        $g = substr($color_code, 1, 1);
        $b = substr($color_code, 2, 1);
        $returncolor = array();
        $returncolor['R'] = max(0, min(255, hexdec($r.$r)));
        $returncolor['G'] = max(0, min(255, hexdec($g.$g)));
        $returncolor['B'] = max(0, min(255, hexdec($b.$b)));
        break;
    }
    case 6: {
        // 6-digit RGB hexadecimal representation
        $returncolor = array();
        $returncolor['R'] = max(0, min(255, hexdec(substr($color_code, 0, 2))));
        $returncolor['G'] = max(0, min(255, hexdec(substr($color_code, 2, 2))));
        $returncolor['B'] = max(0, min(255, hexdec(substr($color_code, 4, 2))));
        break;
    }
```

I read from this post https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/2003 (which involves dompdf, not tcpdf) that it can be an error with PHP's hexdec():

```
Passing invalid characters to base_convert(), bindec(), octdec() and hexdec() will now generate a deprecation notice. The result will still be computed as if the invalid characters did not exist. Leading and trailing whitespace, as well as prefixes of type 0x (depending on base) continue to be allowed.
```

However, since advice given there was not specifically for tcpdf, I'm not sure how best to resolve this issue. Any advice?

**EDIT: I echo'd the value of $color_code before that snippet of code above and it outputs a very large/long hexadecimal number, but the final character has an "l" (el): "000000000000a0892c0000...70d69400d34169el" So I added the following line:**

```
$color_code = substr($color_code, 0, -1);
```

**and the pdf file now generates without error. However, this is not a reliable solution.**

Comment: I think you'll need to inspect `$color_code`

Comment: I echo'd the value of $color_code before that snippet of code and it outputs a very large/long hexadecimal number, but the final character has an "l" (el): "000000000000a0892c0000...70d69400d34169el". I edited my question about this discovery.

Comment: I think you are going to have to walk that code back further, all the way to the [beginning of the function](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF/blob/c4c3e054f3f16d0b0767b55149689bbcb0e0b72f/include/tcpdf_colors.php#L273), and see what arguments were passed